# I am taking values from HTML table. But when I put a variable from javascript to HTML to change next time value, It doesn't accept it

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, variables

Here I'm using **JSP, JAVASCRIPT, HTML in Netbeans 6.9.1**

```
 <table id="table1" class="table table-bordered">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <%= rs.getInt(1)%>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%= rs.getString(2)%>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%= rs.getString(3)%>

            </td>
            <td>
                <%= rs.getString(4)%>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%= rs.getString(5)%>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%= rs.getInt(6)%>

            </td>
            <td>
                <%= rs.getInt(7)%>

            </td  >
            <td>
               <input type="text" placeholder="Quantity" name="qty" id="qty1" oninput="subtotal(document.getElementById('qty1').value)">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="sub">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>





  <script type="text/javascript">
                    var m = 0;
                    function subtotal(a){
                        var x= parseInt(document.getElementById("table1").rows[m].cells[5].innerHTML);
                        var y = parseInt(document.getElementById("table1").rows[m].cells[6].innerHTML);
                        var p = parseInt(a);

                        var z= x+y+p;
                        alert(z);

                        alert(m);
                    }
                </script>
```

in the above code document.getElementById gives me data of first row the table, but for next iteration I want next rows data.

So I tried to put a javascript variable, but the it doesn't works.

Comment: In above code your table is having only one row if your table is having more rows then just increase the variable m in the function subtotal() by 1. (like m++ )

Comment: yeah.. i tried as you said Arpan, but it didn't work!!! It worked for the first run of the function only

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you only have one table row.
But in case this is just an example and in your actual code, you have multiple rows, you just increase your variable `m`;
You can do this like this:
`m++` at the end of your function,
or like this: `m+=1`. Like this, you can increase it by any amount you want.

Answer (score 0):

Please check below code i have added one row and its working for two iteration. U need to check the condition depending on your rows.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
var m = 0;
                function subtotal(a){
                    var x= parseInt(document.getElementById("table1").rows[m].cells[5].innerHTML);
                    var y = parseInt(document.getElementById("table1").rows[m].cells[6].innerHTML);
                    var p = parseInt(a);

                    var z= x+y+p;
                    alert(z);

                    alert(m);
                    m++;

                }

</script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table id="table1" class="table table-bordered">
            <tr>
                <td>
           10
        </td>
                <td>
            20
        </td>
                <td>
          30

        </td>
                <td>
             40
        </td>
                <td>
            50
        </td>
                <td>
           60

        </td>
                <td>
             70

        </td  >
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
           1
        </td>
                <td>
            2
        </td>
                <td>
          3

        </td>
                <td>
             4
        </td>
                <td>
            5
        </td>
                <td>
           6

        </td>
                <td>
             7

        </td  >
                <td>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Quantity" name="qty" id="qty1" oninput="subtotal(document.getElementById('qty1').value)">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="sub">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
```